# While true loop not ending

Tags: python, loops

I have 3 functions. `listener` function calls `check_url` function in every 10 seconds. If this function success on checking, it calls `destroy` function. After `destroy` function done it's job, i want to terminate the `listener` I tried to do it with `finish_control` variable

```
def listener(url):
    while True:
        if finish_control == 1:
            break
        check_url(url)
        sleep(10)

def check_url(url):
    print ("Status: Listening")
    response = urllib.request.urlopen(url)
    data = response.read()
    text = data.decode('utf-8')
    if text == '1':
        print("--Action Started!--")
        destroy(argv.location)

def destroy(location):
    #some work
    print("---Action completed!---")
    finish_control = 1
```

But the while loop inside `listener` doesn't terminate. I also tried with

```
while (finish_control == 0):
```

There is also same problem. How can I make it stop after `destroy` finishes it's job?

Comment: `listener()` function does not "know" the `finish_control` variable

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Make sure `finish_control` is defined globally and in your `destroy` function add the following:

```
global finish_control
```

Comment: i will mark it in few minutes it's not allow me now

Answer (score 3):

The problem is `finish_control` in function `destroy` is local to the function. The `finish_control` in `listener` is not the same variable.  The work around for this is to `return` the values as in

- In your `destroy` method add a line `return 1` instead of `finish_control = 1`
- add a `return` before `destroy(argv.location)`
- accept it in `listener` i.e. `finish_control = check_url(url)`

*Note* - Do not use `global` as it leads to security vulnerabilities

Comment: returning always beats global

Comment: I know you guys are the experts, but could you explain why the language feature exists if it is not secure. I mean why are globals, eval, etc. not considered safe. I mean if a programmer adheres to what they have in mind there should never be a crash in the program, right?

Comment: @MalikBrahimi Refer http://stackoverflow.com/questions/19158339/python-why-are-global-variables-evil